# Google Sheets Add row based on cell number value the count of cell which has value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

- Consider colD contains some value I need to insert rows below based on col D value and it should include the cell containing value. Exp: If cell value D is 1 it should not add any row but if it 2 it should add one row below and it should be loop for all the rows using get.dataRange for creation of rows. 
  Thanks for the help in advance**1]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new rows, try [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method.

**Example:**

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Appends a new row with 3 columns to the bottom of the
// spreadsheet containing the values in the array
sheet.appendRow(["a man", "a plan", "panama"]);
```

There are **more methods** to test, take a look on:

- [insertRowAfter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition), [insertRowBefore()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowbeforebeforeposition)
- [insertRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex)
- [insertRowsAfter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany), [insertRowsBefore()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsbeforebeforeposition,-howmany)

**Example:**

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Shifts all rows down by three
sheet.insertRows(1, 3);
```